# Pure Python - Py3 Matrix with Array or list And Image

Tags: arrays, image, python-3.x, matrix

I have study array module in Python 3 also struct, and use make matrices (without using NUMPY). This reason not use Numpy or PIL libs it's that I wish port my code for use with tablet device (mobile device supports python, example using QPython). Like my PC brooken was used solutions like this for me or other people programming with tablet ( question of price $$ money) and use it construct my modules. 
Well I don't know using array or list have better performance, in this moment I use implementation with list to create simple matrix and matrix for image PPM.

```
 >>> arr = lambda m,n : [ [ for j in range(n)] for i in range(m) ]
 >>> m = arr(2,3)
 >>> m

image = lambda m,n: [ [ {'r':0,'g':0,'b':0} for j in range(n) ] 
                         for i in range(m) ]
```

Comment: Why not use Termux? You can use numpy and maybe (I have not tested it yet) PIL. This would be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks max. 
I see Termux but my version Android not compatible, but I think this way. thank you for your suggestion.